# A question on a function defined on Isometry.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am given as the exercise to prove that the function: $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\to Isom(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where $Isom(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the Isometry group over $\mathbb{R}^n$, is defined as $\varphi: v \mapsto \varphi_v$, where $\varphi_v(x)=x+v$.
I need to prove that $\varphi$ is a group embedding.

I am not sure if it works since I need to show that it's a homomorphism and injective.
If I compute it I need to show the equality: $\varphi(v_1+v_2)=\varphi(v_1)+\varphi(v_2)$, but this is clearly not the case cause on the LHS when acted on $x$ I get: $x+v_1+v_2$ and the RHS is $2x+v_1+v_2$ so we don't necessarily get an equality.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation defined over $Isom(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is not the sum, but the composition $\circ$ of functions. In this way

$\phi(v_1+v_2)(x)=x+v_1+v_2=(\phi(v_1)\circ \phi(v_2))(x)$ for each $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$

Thus $\phi$ is an homomorphism of groups and its kernel is zero, because if $\phi(v)=Id_{\mathbb{R}^n}$, then

$\phi(v)(x)=x+v=Id(x)=x$ implies $v=0$

A simple remark is that this subgroup (that is called the group of translations of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ) of $Isom(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is abelian and normal.